# Angular 2 conditional redirect of homepage

Tags: angular, typescript, redirect

I made a guard to conditionally redirect from the homepage, in the app.routing.ts:

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [HomePageGuard] }
```

My guard looks something like this:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
if(condition){
  return true;
} else {
  this.router.navigate(['/info']);
  return false;
}
}
```

Now for every other path, this works great. But for

```
{ path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

The guard doesn't seem to do anything, it always redirects to /dashboard, no matter what the guard returns.
I don't want to put the guard into the /dashboard path, because this path should still be available for everyone, just not as the start page...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

edit:
How i solved it for now:

```
{ path: '', component: HomePageComponent, canActivate: [HomePageGuard] }
```

(note that the HomePageComponent is empty, since it gets redirected in the [HomePageGuard] either way)

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
if(condition){
  this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
  return false;
} else {
  this.router.navigate(['/start']);
  return false;
}
}
```

Comment: Your route entry with the guard looks bonkus - shouldn't it be "{ path: '', canActivate: [HomePageGuard] }

Comment: it redirects to `dashboard` but what do you want check on dashboard ?

Comment: Sorry i'm late to answer,

@Vega which code do you mean, the whole app.routing.ts ?

Comment: @koe i need to have either a redirect or a component, simply using { path: '', canActivate: [HomePageGuard] } throws an error

Comment: @RahulSingh i don't necessarily want to check something on the dashboard, i want to redirect users from the base path (path:' ') to either /dashboard or /start, based on a condition (which is in the [HomePageGuard] and works for every other path, but not for the empty one). 

Thanks for helping btw

Comment: I thought more about the home page

Comment: @JustYourCasualProgrammer what is your base href?

Comment: @Vega there isn't exactly a homepage, it's either /start or /dashboard, depending on the user settings. Do i need one? I thought i could just redirect to the right one

Comment: @RahulSingh the site isn't online as of now, we just have a test api with a db containing some mock data, so there isn't a base href if i understood your question correctly? why does it matter?

Comment: @JustYourCasualProgrammer no the base href in index.html of angualr

Comment: @RahulSingh oh, it's just <base href="/">

Comment: i seem to have found a solution that works, but there would probably a better way to solve this (see my edit in the main post)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5: Conditionally Set Default Route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50700718/angular-5-conditionally-set-default-route)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50721679/856373), the guard isn't invoked at all when a `redirect` is specified.

Comment: Instead of posting an answer which merely links to another answer, please instead [flag the question](/help/privileges/flag-posts) as a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks, @Yatin. I've flagged the question as a duplicate.